# SSH key turns invalid shortly after being added in github

Tags: validation, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm generating an SSH key on Ubuntu according to instructions on GitHub. And at first when I run `ssh -T git@github.com` everything seems fine and the key is validated. However, next time I try to push or pull from a repo it says the key is invalid, and if I run `ssh -T git@github.com` again it says "Permission denied (publickey)". I've generated several new keys and it's the same every time, they work at first but after just a few minutes they turn invalid. What's going on?

Comment: Are you doing anything else in those few minutes, such as something that would touch those keys again? Can you provide the output of `ssh -vv -T git@github.com` for better debugging?

Comment: "it says the key is invalid" *What* says the key is invalid, and what's the exact text?